# How do you know if a likelihood function is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, inference

I have the following function $f(x|\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^\alpha} x^{\alpha-1}, 0\le x \le \beta$ and taking its likelihood I have the following result,
$$lik(\alpha,\beta|x)=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha}{\beta^\alpha} x_i^{\alpha-1}*I_{[0,\beta]}(X_i) \\
=\frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^{n\alpha}} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha-1}*I_{[0,\beta]}(X_{(n)})*I_{[0,\infty]}(X_{(1)})$$

Where $X_{(n)}$ and $X_{(1)}$ are order statistics.

Now as I'm trying to find the mle of $\beta$ I'm not understanding the solutions answer of "For any fixed $\alpha,lik(\alpha,\beta|x)=0$ if $\beta<X_{(n)}$ and $lik(\alpha,\beta|x)$ a decreasing function of $\beta$ if $\beta \ge X_{(n)}$. Thus, $X_{(n)}$ is the mle of $\beta$." If you're able to provide a simple graph, that would help me a lot as I'm a visual person.

So my question is, how is $lik(\alpha,\beta|x)$ a decreasing function of $\beta$ if $\beta \ge X_{(n)}$ as I'm having a hard visualizing how this is a decreasing function.

Comment: As $\beta$ gets larger, the value of the likelihood function gets smaller, because $\beta$ is both positive and only in the denominator.

Comment: @jbowman, wow thank you. I knew it was something easy that I was missing and now with this understanding that we are only interested in the function that variable is associated with makes me understand this problem and others a lot more when it comes to indicator functions. i.e. the function of interest is $1/\beta$. Thank you for the explination.

Comment: Yes, the value of the indicator function doesn't change with changes in $\beta$ as long as $\beta \geq x_{[n]}$, it's just a way of writing a constraint on $\beta$, and therefore can be ignored unless the solution winds up at the boundary $\beta = x_{[n]}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize it as a function of $\beta$

$$lik(\alpha,\beta|x)=\begin{cases}0& \quad \text{if $\beta < X_{(n)}$}\\
\vphantom{\frac{1}{\beta^{n\alpha}}} \smash{\underbrace{{\frac{1}{\beta^{n\alpha}} }}_{\llap{\text{decreasing f}}\rlap{\text{unction of $\beta$}}} }\,\cdot \,\overbrace{ \alpha^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha-1}}^{\text{constant term}} & \quad \text{if $\beta \geq X_{(n)}$}
\end{cases}
\vphantom{\begin{cases}0& \quad \text{if $\beta < X_{(n)}$}\\
{\frac{1}{\beta^{n\alpha}}} {\overbrace{{\frac{1}{\beta^{n\alpha}} }}^{\llap{\text{decreasing f}}\rlap{\text{unction of $\beta$}}}} \cdot \alpha^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha-1} & \quad \text{if $\beta \geq X_{(n)}$}  \cdot \overbrace{ \alpha^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha-1}}^{\text{constant term}}
\\t\\t\\t
\end{cases}}
$$

If this is still too abstract then choose some example data and make a plot of the likelihood for that data.